# Pandas transform two columns of lists into a columns dictionary with repeated keys

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe called: `self.data`
They have two columns: `name` and `value` and I want a new one to be generated with a dictionary.
For example:

| Name | Value | New Dict Column |
| --- | --- | --- |
| [a, b, c, a] | [1, 2, 3, 4] | {a: [1, 4], b: [2], c: [3]} |
| [b, b, a] | [1, 2, 3] | {b: [1, 2], a: [3] } |

At this moment I have the following code:

```py
data['dict'] = self.data[['name', 'value']].apply(lambda x: dict(zip(*x)), axis=1)
```

The problem with this attempt is that the pair name, value is being always replaced. Using the example, I can't save both a1 and a2. The final dictionary only stores the last one.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Both are working! Thank you for your help. Upvoted both since are both answers are fine.

Comment: Added performance comparison to my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use custom function with `defaultdict` if performance is important:

```
from collections import defaultdict

def f(x):
    d = defaultdict(list)
    for y, z in zip(*x):
        d[y].append(z)
    return d

df['New Dict Column'] = [ f(x) for x in df[['column1','column2']].to_numpy()]
print(df)
        column1       column2                    New Dict Column
0  [a, b, c, a]  [1, 2, 3, 4]  {'a': [1, 4], 'b': [2], 'c': [3]}
1     [b, b, a]     [1, 2, 3]            {'b': [1, 2], 'a': [3]}
```

Performance is really good, 10 times faster:

```
#20k rows for test
df = pd.concat([df] * 10000, ignore_index=True)


In [211]: %timeit df.apply(lambda data: {k: [y for x, y in zip(data[0], data[1]) if x == k] for k in data[0]}, axis=1)
532 ms ± 2.54 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [212]: %timeit  [ f(x) for x in df[['column1','column2']].to_numpy()]
53.8 ms ± 596 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this with `apply`:

```
df['New Dict Column'] = df.apply(lambda data: {k: [y for x, y in zip(data[0], data[1]) if x == k] for k in data[0]}, axis=1)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
           Name         Value                    New Dict Column
0  [a, b, c, a]  [1, 2, 3, 4]  {'a': [1, 4], 'b': [2], 'c': [3]}
1     [b, b, a]     [1, 2, 3]            {'b': [1, 2], 'a': [3]}
```

Comment: That was a very interesting solution. I edited the question when the values are only simple integers. This will make the `y[0] == k` not working properly

Comment: It works! I was actually doing now a similar thing based on your first response. Thank you @U12-Forward

Answer (score 0):

You can use apply for several columns with the next pattern:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Name' :[['a', 'b', 'c', 'a'], ['b', 'b', 'a']], 
                   'Value' :[['a1', 'b1', 'c1', 'a2'], ['b1', 'b2', 'a1']]})
                   
print(df)

def get_dict(row):
    my_dict = {}
    for x in row['Name']:
        my_dict[x] = row['Value']
    return my_dict
    

df['my_dict'] = df.apply(get_dict, axis=1)

print(df)
```

PS: take into account that I have not define correctly the way to extract the right elements from Value to be mapped to the right element of Name. You will need to implement that part of the code.